# is there a full Nextcloud API accessable from outside?

Tags: api, rest, nextcloud

I use Nextcloud as a normal user to store and share files.

I decided to use it as a backend for a web application I am developing so that I can store the files in Nextcloud while the frontend is done by me.

I spent some hours on the API docs
https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/index.html

and, with some disappointment, unless I have not made a mistake, I realized that the only API that can be used from outside Nextcloud is the WebDav API.
This is a minimalistic API that allows doing basic things such as uploading a file by passing the full path like with this GET statement (authenticated by basic auth passing username and password in the headers:

```
GET https://nextcloud.example.com/remote.php/dav/files/username/FolderOne/SubFolderTwo/HelloWorld.txt
```

This will download the file located in /FolderOne/SubFolderTwo/HelloWorld.txt

with a `PUT` request, it is possible to overwrite the file by passing the file content in the raw body request

This is very effective but minimalistic.

I was expecting to have a full REST API to access more properties and perform complex operations.

Could you please tell me if I missed some important information?

There is the OCS API but it works only from inside Nextcloud.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A full REST API is avaiable - https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/22/developer_manual/client_apis/OCS/ocs-api-overview.html

Create a Share - https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/OCS/ocs-share-api.html

The OwnCloud documentation also offers more examples
https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.8/developer_manual/core/apis/ocs-share-api.html

You can register an App id and use that to login or passthru a username and password in the authentication header.